# How can i change the default name "Areas" to "<MyOwnAreaName>Areas" in MVC2?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm using MVC 2, I need to change the default name "Areas" to `<MyOwnAreaName>`.

Is't possible to change default name "Areas" to my own name??

Can any one help to give the solution, thanks in advance.

Comment: what reason do you have for needing to change the name "areas"?  that would be like changing "controllers" or "views".  by sticking with convention you are going to save yourself a lot of trouble.

Comment: Are you trying to change the name of an area, or of the folder that contains all area-specific content?

Answer (score 5):

You could write a [custom virtual path provider](http://www.michaelfcollins3.me/2010/12/asp-net-mvc-views-gone-crazy/). Here are the default values that you might be interested in overriding:

```
MasterLocationFormats = new[] 
{
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.master"
};

AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[] 
{
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
};

ViewLocationFormats = new[] 
{
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
    "~/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
    "~/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx"
};

AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] 
{
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
    "~/Areas/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
};
```

So here's how this might look in your case:

```
public class CustomViewEngine : WebFormViewEngine
{
    public CustomViewEngine()
    {
        AreaMasterLocationFormats = new[] 
        {
            "~/MyOwnAreaName/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.master",
            "~/MyOwnAreaName/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.master",
        };

        AreaViewLocationFormats = new[] 
        {
            "~/MyOwnAreaName/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.aspx",
            "~/MyOwnAreaName/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.ascx",
            "~/MyOwnAreaName/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.aspx",
            "~/MyOwnAreaName/{2}/Views/Shared/{0}.ascx",
        };
    }
}
```

and then register this custom engine in `Application_Start`:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ...
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new CustomViewEngine());
}
```

Now you could place the area files in `~/MyOwnAreaName`.

Remark/Advice: stick to the ASP.NET MVC conventions as much as possible and override them only if strictly necessary.